# Vue package dependency conflict, Found vue@2.6.14

Tags: vue.js

I am inheriting a project and it was built on Vue 2, I believe the problem is I have Vue 3 installed on my system (I am on macOS).

Rather new to Vue so I apologize if the answer is obvious.

My package.json...
You can see here that my vue version is 2.6.10, I believe the error is stating I have 3.0 installed, possibly globally, on my host system. I am not sure how to get around this, I need Vue 3 installed on my system for another project, I believe that is what is conflicting.

```
{
  "name": "test-vuetify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "plotly.js": "^1.52.2",
    "plotly.js-cartesian-dist-min": "^1.54.5",
    "sinon": "^8.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-json-csv": "^1.2.12",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-toast-notification": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.28",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^4.2.95",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "canvas": "^2.9.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.18.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.2"
  }
}
```

The error when I do npm install...

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-toast-notification@3.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^2.6.10" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"2.x" from @vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.31
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/test-utils
npm ERR!     dev @vue/test-utils@"1.0.0-beta.31" from the root project
npm ERR!   7 more (vue-class-component, vue-jest, vue-json-csv, vue-moment, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.0" from vue-toast-notification@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-toast-notification
npm ERR!   vue-toast-notification@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.37
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.0" from vue-toast-notification@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-toast-notification
npm ERR!     vue-toast-notification@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error source is in `vue-toast-notification@3.0.0`:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-toast-notification@3.0.0
```

The issue that is mentioned:

```
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
…
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.0" from vue-toast-notification@3.0.0
```

This error means that library `vue-toast-notification@3.0.0` requires Vue in version 3 to work correctly (there is mentioned version as peer dependency, I  also confirmed it on their [docs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toast-notification)). In other words, you're using an incompatible library for your project. You have Vue@2 project where you installed a dependency package dedicated for Vue@3 project.
To fix it you need to install `vue-toast-notification` as a dependency with a version dedicated for vue@2. In this case, it should be [`vue-toast-notification@^0.6`](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-toast-notification/tree/v1.x#vue-toast-notification).

Comment: It's [vue-toast-notification@^1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toast-notification)

Comment: @tao branch is called `1.x`, however when you check the released version on npm there is `0.6.2`, then `2.0.0` and linked tag to `1.x` goes to the repository where author suggests to install it as version `^0.6`.

Comment: I'm guessing they wrote `1.x` at the very top of the docs because they intend to publish a stable 1 at some point. Most likely, your answer will still work for future users, at that point, but, technically, it will cease to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are on vue 3 and need to install node modules for vue 2 project use legacy
  peer deps to install modules for vue 2 project node modules
- or you can achieve this by downgrading your node package manager(npm) that works
  for you

  npm install --legacy-peer-deps

  npm install -g npm@6.14.8

Answer (score 0):

I think these issues are related to npm, so if you try yarn instead, as I did, or perhaps pnpm, then it just works.